# forwarding ports from eth0 to wlan0

Tags: raspbian, internet, iptables, hotspot, port-forwarding

I have a raspberry pi 3 which is set up as a wifi ap using hostapd and dnsmasq sharing the eth0 which is connected to an ADSL modem. My laptop is connected to this wifi ap. I have set up vnc servers on both the pi(port 5900) and my laptop(port 5901) using xrdp using same settings. I could see the piś screen from the internet because i have port forwarded ports 1 to 65530 from the ADSL modem to the pi. how can i setup port forwarding so that i could see the laptopś screen from the internet?

the setup is as shown

Internet ======ADSL Modem ======Pi==========Laptop

I could access the pi from the internet. I could not access the laptop from the internet. But i have internet access on both the laptop and on the pi

I have tried using iptables with no success.